# a Function with several periods

Tags: fourier-analysis, periodic-functions

A periodic function is given by $ f(x+nT)=f(x) $, with 'n' an integer and T the period.

My question is if we can define a non-constant function with several periods; by that, I mean

$ f(x+T_{i})=f(x) $ with $ i=1,2,3,4,\dots $ a set of different numbers.

For example, a function that satisfies $ f(x+2)=f(x) $, as well as $ f(x+5.6)=f(x) $ and  $ f(x+ \sqrt 2) =f(x) $, but $ f(x) $ is NOT a constant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are the elliptic functions, which are functions that have two (in general) *complex* periods. It is a deep theorem of the theory of elliptic functions that the ratio of these two periods is necessarily not real. This was proven by [C.G.J. Jacobi in 1835](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.1835.13.55), who also showed that there cannot be a single-valued function of one variable that has more than two periods.

Comment: See [this](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=N2pX-wMEIb4C&pg=PA17) as well.

Answer (score 4):

If we work with functions from the real line to itself, we have several cases. Since the set of periods of a function is a subgroup of the additive group of the real, it is either dense in $\Bbb R$ (for the usual topology) or discrete (of the form $a\Bbb Z$ for some $a\in\Bbb R$.

If $G$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb R$, then the characteristic function of $G$ is $g$-periodic for each $g\in G$.

The group of the periods of a continuous function is either $\Bbb R$ (constant functions) or discrete.

Comment: OK, discrete, and what?

Answer (score 0):

Dirichlet function is not a constant and has both 2 and 5.6 as its periods. But there is no smallest period.

Comment: Dirichlet function is a periodic function with no definite period.

Comment: @Aniket it has no smallest period but has other periods.

Comment: What do you mean by "it has no smallest period"?